# How to get rank from Google Play game service's leaderboard?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I'm working on a big application and I have to take the player's rank from the Google Play services' leaderboard. The leaderboard works well. I've already found the right method but I don't know how I'm supposed to use it:

```
private void loadRankOfLeaderBoard() {
    Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult scoreResult) {
            if (isScoreResultValid(scoreResult)) {
                rank = (int)scoreResult.getScore().getRank();                
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But the `onResult` callback is never called. Where am I supposed to call the function loadRankOfLeaderBoard?? I tried to put it in the `onCreate` and in the `onActivityResult`...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finnaly found solution ... [here for curious](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.Leaderboards)

So if you have the same problem, you have to put the function loadRankOfLeaderBoard on the function "onConnected" which will be call when you connect your device at google play service.