# leaderboarScore.getRawScore() work fine but getRank() allways returns LEADERBOARD_RANK_UNKNOWN

Tags: google-play-services

I'm trying to display the current score and rank of a player without the standard UI. The problem is that the rank is allways -1. I've displayed the standard leaderboard UI and my position is "1" (I'm the only player xD). I can't imagine what's wrong. Here is my code.

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_global),
                LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult scoreResult) {
                if(scoreResult != null && scoreResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    mGeneralScore = scoreResult.getScore();
                    mGeneralScore.getRawScore();//return the score
                    mGeneralScore.getRank();//return -1
                    mGeneralScore.getDisplayRank();//return "unknow" 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610936/how-to-get-rank-from-google-play-game-services-leaderboard

Comment: No, my problem isn't related with the callback itself. I receive the score result with many data(like player name or raw score), but the rank data is allwais unknow.