# Android - How to get user rank from Google Play Game Service's leaderboards?

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

GPS Leaderboard can show user **score**, like in this link [How to get rank from Google Play game service's leaderboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610936/how-to-get-rank-from-google-play-game-services-leaderboard).

But, how to get user **rank** and place them on activity? It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [`getRank()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore#getRank()) method which retrieves the rank returned from the server for this score. Note that this may not be exact and that multiple scores can have identical ranks. Lower ranks indicate a better score, with rank 1 being the best score on the board.

> If the score holder's rank cannot be determined, this will return [`LEADERBOARD_RANK_UNKNOWN`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html#LEADERBOARD_RANK_UNKNOWN).
>
> **Returns**
>
> - Rank of score.

Comment: I've already studied all the answers on Stack and all the Google documentation and still withou nothing when and how can I call this .getRank()... Could someone tell me what do I need to call it? I would be really grateful